# To find square by reference of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void square (int *);

int main () {

    int number = 0;

    cout << " To find the square of the number entered by the user ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << square (&number);

    return 0;
}

void square (int *x) 
{
    *x = *x ** x;
}
```

can anyone tell what is the error in this code,because it gives me kind of big lengthy weird error

Comment: Why not post that error?

Comment: : error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: can you please explain it, this is the short form of that specific error

Comment: In addition to using `address of` and `dereferences`, you can use a `c++ reference`. E.g.: In `main ... square (number); ...` then `void square (int& x) { x = x * x; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `square` does not return a value it cannot pass anything to `cout`

Instead change the line

```
 cout << square (&number);
```

to

```
 square (&number);
 cout << number;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `main()` expects `square()` to `return` the result, while square is a `void` function that modifies its argument in-place.

The error message is saying basically that: there is no `operator<<` that takes `void` as it's right-hand argument.

Comment: I have been down voted as well :-( I have just up voted as the down vote was unfair

Comment: Go figure. Probably immaturity masquerading as a **sour grapes** downvote. Takes all kinds lately.